# Failed building wheel for duckdb

Tags: python, duckdb

I am getting this message after entering pip3 install duckdb through pyCharm terminal.

ERROR: Could not build wheels for duckdb, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

i am getting the same message trying to install other packages like pygwalker

i used pip3 install duckdb and pygwalker.

Comment: This is not the complete error message. Please post complete error message beginning at the word *Traceback*. Include it in your question as text not as links or images. Copy and Paste the entire stack trace into your question.

Comment: thanks for responding. i actually figured out the issue - i was using python 3.12 but apparently there are a lot of packages not available for it. when i switched to 3.11 i can now install all these packages

Comment: Glad you figured it out. In case of next time, it's advisable to include full error messages in your question. One would have probably spotted your version of python in the Traceback and suggested a solution. Happy coding!

Comment: DuckDB now supports Python 3.12.

Answer (score 7):

**Update: DuckDB's stable version now supports Python 3.12. Simply install it via:**

```
pip install duckdb
```

**Old answer:**

This was caused due to a lack of support for Python 3.12 in DuckDB 0.9.2.

Python 3.12 is now supported by DuckDB's nightly release. This is currently available by running the following command:

```
pip install duckdb --upgrade --pre
```

It will be included in version 0.10.0, released in a few weeks.